# Urban Airship iOS push notification missing 'alert' property when using UA Java Client

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using [UA java client](https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library) in a Grails project.

```
compile 'com.urbanairship:java-client:0.2.2'
```

All silent notifications sent to iOS devices work fine.

However non silent notifications don't work because they miss the *'alert'* property in *'aps'* dictionary in the delivered [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

The delivered notification looks like this:

```
{
    "_" = XzqmAId1EeSkv5DiugJkgA;
    action = ready;
    aps =     {
        badge = 0; 
        sound = "notify.caf";
    };
    x = 28984;
    y = 103; 
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "_" = "XzqmAId1EeSkv5DiugJkgA";
    action = ready;
    aps =     {
        alert =  {
            "loc-key" = "ORDER_IS_READY";
        };
        badge = 0;
        sound = "notify.caf";
    };
    x = 28984;
    y = 103;
}
```

Here is how the various push notification properties are set up using the java client library in the Grails App:

```
APIClient apiClient = APIClient.newBuilder()
        .setKey("key")
        .setSecret("secret")
        .build()

IOSBadgeData iosBadgeData = IOSBadgeData.newBuilder()
        .setValue(getValueFromSomewhere())
        .setType(IOSBadgeData.Type.VALUE)
        .build()

IOSAlertData iosAlertData = IOSAlertData.newBuilder()
        .setLocKey("ORDER_IS_READY")
        .build()

IOSDevicePayload iosDevicePayload = IOSDevicePayload.newBuilder()
        .setAlert(iosAlertData)
        .setSound("notify.caf")
        .setBadge(iosBadgeData)
        .addAllExtraEntries(attributesMapContainingXandY)
        .build()

Notification notification = Notifications.notification(iosDevicePayload)
Selector selector = Selectors.deviceToken(getIosDeviceId())
PushPayload payload = PushPayload.newBuilder()
                        .setAudience(selector)
                        .setNotification(notification)
                        .setDeviceTypes(DeviceTypeData.of(DeviceType.IOS))
                        .build()
APIClientResponse<APIPushResponse> response = apiClient.push(payload)
```

If I print the *iosDevicePayLoad* I could see it having the alert localization key, i.e., "ORDER_IS_READY".

Has anybody faced similar problem when using the [UA Java Client library](https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library)?

Thanks

Comment: There are two branches on UA Java Client library and they both try to address the same problem above. https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library/compare/locArgs  and https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library/compare/master...ios-alert-data-serialize-fix

Comment: Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library/issues/12

Comment: Fix is waiting for a merge in master branch https://github.com/urbanairship/java-library/pull/25